# react-native api call got stuck

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am doing a simple API call in a  function. The API Response is fine in Postman it 280 ms to 340 ms. but in my Application it takes 5 to 10 mins. Here is my function:

```
const getSuggestions = async query => {
    const filterToken = query.toLowerCase();
    if (query.length < 3) {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append(
      'Authorization',
      'Basic xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzyzyzyzy',
    );
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
      query: filterToken,
      language: 'en',
    });
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow',
    };
    fetch(
      'https://api.worldota.net/api/b2b/v3/search/multicomplete/',
      requestOptions,
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        const sections = [];
        Object.keys(response.data).map((item, i) => {
          sections.push({
            title: item,
            data: response.data[item],
          });
        });
        setSuggestionsList(sections);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Whenever my search params are changed then I call this function. What is the problem with my function? It was working fine last day. :(

Comment: You didnt ask a question

Comment: i have edited this now. please check now. why my api call got stuck